# Ho can I report sub-class values where sub-classes are stored in a std::vector<parent-class>

Tags: c++

I have a std::vector of smart pointers to the parent class animals.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<animal>> farm;
```

Sub-classes cat, dog, and mouse each have the parent class animal.
Only cat, dog, and mouse are pointed to in the vector. Like this

```
class cat : public animal {
public:
    bool claws;
};

farm.push_back(std::make_shared<cat>());
farm.push_back(std::make_shared<dog>());
farm.push_back(std::make_shared<mouse>());
```

Cat also has public member cat.claws (type bool).

I know farm[0].claws won't work because claws isn't a virtual member of farm.  Is there a way to access claws when looping through farm without creating a separate virtual function?  In the actual problem I have many different sub-class variables I'd like to report to the user as the program loops over farm (indefinitely).

Comment: the key thing is intention here... *why* do you want to access `claws`?

Comment: It's for reporting purposes.  The virtual functions for each sub-class which I process in the loop are dependent on each sub-classes unique set of variables.  I'd like to report these unique variables as well since they change during run-time.

Comment: so do it from a virtual function - where you know which sub-class the object is.

Comment: That's my current strategy, but it clutters the code, I was hoping c++ had some hidden trick that would provide a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: it doesn't clutter. you don't need tricks. it's very clear - unless, of course, if you completely misunderstood the method. post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) or [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) for this, for example like this:

```
if(auto catPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<cat>(animalPtr))
{
    // now you use catPtr.claws
}
```

(assuming animalPtr is of type `std::shared_ptr<animal>`)

Comment: I'll try implementing this tonight, looks like what I was hoping for.